# java restaurant address displays incorrectly

Tags: java, string

I have an assignment that asks us to input our favorite restaurant and address. I cannot get the address to print out right on the same line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Restaurant {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

String name;
System.out.print("Enter your Favorite Restaurant: ");
name = user_input.next();

String street;
System.out.print("Enter the Street Address: ");
street = user_input.next();

String city;
System.out.print("Enter the City: ");
city = user_input.next();

String state;
System.out.print("Enter the State: ");
state = user_input.next();

String zip;
System.out.print("Enter the Zip Code: ");
zip = user_input.next();


String restaurant = name + "\n" + city + ", " + state + ", " + " " " + zip;"
+ "";


 }
}
```

I get an output that does not let me input the whole address properly. There must be an easier way to do this.

```
Enter your Favorite Restaurant: Uncle Bubs
Enter the Street Address: Enter the City: 444 Spender St
Enter the State: Enter the Zip Code: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19        seconds)
```

Comment: give an example input and output so we can see what you mean

Comment: Escape `"` as "\ then it may work. And if you want it on same line then remove `\n`. Use `System.out.println`

Comment: @Nilesh: I think you mean `\"`

Comment: oops...sorry yes you are right...will edit it...thanks...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner.next` is used for one word without any spaces.
Any words after that will be saved for the next call to `Scanner.next`.
Instead, use `Scanner.nextLine`:

```
street = scanner.nextLine();
```